# Using using left joins and group by - eliminate duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlperformance

I have 2 tables that I want to join together and group it to get client membership info. My code works for joining but when I try to sum and group the columns, it starts breaking and I can't figure out why.

```
BASE TABLE : sales_detail 
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
|   order_date | transaction_id|   product_cost |  payment_type  |    country
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------+
|   10/1     |   12345         |      20       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/1     |   12345         |      50       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/5     |  82456          |      50       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/9     |  64789          |      30       |      visa       |    canada
|   10/15    |  08546          |      20       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/15    |  08546          |      90       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/17    |  65898          |       50       |      mastercard |   usa
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

```
table : client_information
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   transaction_ID | client_Type|   membership  
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|   12345        |   new         | vip         |
|   12345        |   new         | vip         |
|   82456        |   old         | normal      | 
|   08157        |   old         | vip         |
|   08546        |   old         | normal      |  
|   08546        |   old         | normal      |
|   65898        |   new         | vip         |
|   06587        |   new         | vip         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**I want the output to look something like this: **

```
IDEAL OUTPUT
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|   order_date | transaction_ID |   product_cost |  client_Type|   membership 
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
|   10/1     |   12345         |      70       |      new        |   vip     |
|   10/12    |   82456         |      50       |      old        |   normal  |
|   10/15    |   08546         |      110      |      old        |   normal  |
|   10/17    |   65898         |      50       |      new        |   vip  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

**i am trying to add up the product cost by transaction ID so I can aggregate product cost by client type or membership without having repeats since each transaction id represents one item**

This is the code i used but it failed to group the items I needed :

```
select t1.order_date ,t1.transaction_ID,sum(t1.product_cost), t2.client_type, t2.membership
from sales_detail  t1
inner join client_information t2 on t1.transaction_ID=t2.transaction_ID 
where t1.payment_type='mastercard' and t1.order_date between '2020-01-02' and'2020-02-15'
and country_of_origin != 'canada'
GROUP BY t1.transaction_ID;
```

Thanks in advance! I am a beginner so still learning the ins and outs of sql! (am using hive)

Comment: Why do you have duplicates in the `client_information` table?  Perhaps you need to fix your data before querying it.

Comment: theres duplicates because the each transaction_id represents a single product.

Comment: A quick fix: change `join client_information t2 on ...` to `join (select distinct * from client_information) t2 on ...`

Comment: @eazyzz . . . That makes no sense.  The clients table should have one row per client  The transactions table should have one row per transaction.  And the sales details table should have one row per product in each transaction.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned in the comments, the table structure is odd where the client_information table would have multiple rows. But, if that's how it is, then you need distinct values to avoid duplication.

Does your version of mysql support the "with" clause? I'm not a mysql user, but this works on postgres. You may need to slightly adjust for mysql, not sure.

```
    with client_info as 
    (select distinct transaction_id, client_type, membership
    from client_information
    )
    select s.order_date, s.transaction_id, c.client_type, c.membership, sum(s.product_cost) as total_cost
    from sales_detail s
    join client_info c 
        on c.transaction_id = s.transaction_id
    where s.payment_type = 'mastercard'
    and s.country <> 'canada' --assuming country is always populated
    and --input your date logic
    group by s.order_date, s.transaction_id, c.client_type, c.membership
```

Results:

```
    order_date;trans_id;client_type;membership;total_cost

    10/1;12345;new;vip;70

    10/15;8546;old;normal;110

    10/17;65898;new;vip;50

    10/5;82456;old;normal;50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get accurately what I think you want and here is why.  When you are saving the sales detail line and creating what appears to be a 1:1 line in the client information table, there is nothing that EXPLICITLY dictates that the first line in sales detail matches the first line in client information, second matches second, etc.  This is allowing you to get a Cartesian result as the only match you have is the ID.  Now it is convenient that both lines in the transaction table show the same ID, type and membership, but would it EVER be a single transaction with same ID, but differing type/membership?  I don't think so, but you are only showing enough detail on the rows to cover the query, not the full (which is ok).

Anyhow, as user "isolated" provided in their sample using the "WITH" construct, that is not much more than masking a query directly in the main query.  You need to first get the DISTINCT components from the transaction, THEN you can summarize the data.

That said, here is the query without using the "WITH" context.

```
select
      max( sd.order_date ) Order_Date,
      sd.transaction_id,
      sum( sd.product_cost ) TransactionTotalCost,
      max( ci.client_type ) Client_Type,
      max( ci.membership ) Membership
   from
      sales_detail sd
         JOIN ( select distinct
                      transaction_id,
                      client_type,
                      membership
                   from
                      client_information ) ci
            on sd.transaction_id = ci.transaction_id
   where
          sd.payment_type='mastercard' 
      and sd.order_date between '2020-01-02' and'2020-02-15'
      and sd.country != 'canada'
   group by
      sd.transaction_id
```

Now, the above will work, but I have some additional suggestions.  Depending on the size of your data the inner JOIN that is getting all distinct values, that is getting distinct values against your ENTIRE DATA, not just the dates in question.  To prevent this, I will be making this inner query a PRE-Query result joined to the sales detail table so I am only getting those transactions within the date qualified, thus resulting in a smaller set.  THEN joining to the sales detail table.  I would only suggest and assume the sales detail table SHOULD have an index on the transaction id as well as others to optimize the join.

Lastly, and just for future consideration is querying with dates.  Using the "BETWEEN" clause can cause a bit of a problem with unexpected results.  If your date column is just a date, no problem.  But if the date field is a date/time, then the query for between '2020-01-02' and '2020-02-15' wont necessarily get transactions with a dateTime of '2020-02-15 14:27:35' since 2:27 in the afternoon is AFTER an implied 2020-02-15 at 12:00:00 in the morning and could thus leave records out.  My preference is to do >= starting date AND < day following your intended date.. you'll see in the query.

```
select
      max( sd2.order_date ) Order_Date,
      preQuery.transaction_id,
      sum( sd2.product_cost ) TransactionTotalCost,
      max( preQuery.client_type ) Client_Type,
      max( preQuery.membership ) Membership
   from
      ( select distinct
              sd.transaction_id,
              ci.client_type,
              ci.membership
            from
               sales_detail sd
                  JOIN client_information ci
                     on sd.transaction_id = ci.transaction_id
            where
                   sd.payment_type='mastercard' 
               and sd.order_date >= '2020-01-02' 
               and sd.order_Date < '2020-02-16'
               and sd.country != 'canada'
      ) preQuery
         JOIN sales_detail sd2
            on preQuery.Transaction_ID = sd2.Transaction_ID
   group by
      preQuery.transaction_id
```

So above, the inner pre-query pre-qualifies all the details on the pay type, date range and NOT Canada.  Only then does it go back to the actual sales detail (via second alias of sd2) to get your sum of cost and order date.